# How to trigger Alert after Server Error Response with Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, dropzone.js

I want to trigger a javascript alert from dropzone.js when the server returns an error. (in json).

Here is my function/method.  It seems to be working fine.

```
public function file_upload($account_id,$bid_id) {
    $path = FMREPO . "/account-" . $account_id . "/bid-project-" .$bid_id . "/";
    if (file_exists ( $path )){
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
            $targetPath = $path . "diagram-" . $bid_id . "-";
            $targetFile = $targetPath . $fileName ;
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
                // $this->load->database(); // load database
                // $this->db->insert('file_table',array('file_name' => $fileName));
        }
    } else{
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Directory Not Found');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('error' => 'File Could Not Be Saved')));
    }   
}
```

Here is my Dropzone options. This is the part I don't know how to do or make it work. The "error:" is what I added but it always triggers an alert, even when the file upload was successfull.  What do I need to do here?

```
Dropzone.options.diagramDropzone = {
paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
maxFilesize: 6, // MB
maxFiles: 2,
thumbnailWidth: 100,
thumbnailHeight: 100,
error: function(){
    alert('error');
},
init: function() {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
        alert("No more files please!");
        console.log(file);
        this.removeFile(file);
    });
}
```

}

Edit: I just realized this

`error: function(){
       //alert here
    },`

should be

`error: function(response){
        //alert here
},`

so now that is working!  But the with `alert(response)` I get [object].  So now the question is how do I alert my string?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up you alert inside the init option like this:

```
init: function() {
    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
        alert("No more files please!");
        console.log(file);
        this.removeFile(file);
    }),
    this.on("error", function(file, errorMessage, xhr) {
        alert(errorMessage);
    ])
}
```